# Jquery Select2 plugin won't apply to the inputs rendered after a JS call to rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using `select2` plugin for dropdown menus in a rails application. However if i'm rendering a form with a JS call to server select2 is not applied to the inputs.

Here is a js.erb file describing what I mean

```
$("#container").html("<%= j render partial: 'form' %>");
$(".select-list").select2()
```

I've tried setting the context with:

```
$(".select-list", document).select2()
```

But that doesn't work either. How can I apply select2 to my inputs after a server responds to a JS call?

Comment: Have you checked by placing the select2.js on the top of the layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are replacing the content of the `#container` you need to bind the `select2` or any other events for that matter with the `jQuery` `on` method (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

So doing the following should solve your issue:

On your `js.erb`:

```
$("#container").html("<%= j render partial: 'form' %>").trigger('show');
```

Then on your `assets/javascripts/somefile.js.erb`, as long as `somefile.js.erb` is included in your `application.js`, or you could even place the following at the bottom of your `application.js`:

```
$('#container').on('show', function() {
    $('.select-list').select2();
});
```

Comment: @innocent_rifle, Awesome!  Glad to be of help.